# Powershell, Get-WindowsCapability: Why am I getting an error about the path format being unsupported?

Tags: powershell, ssh, path, admin

I am running the script pasted below:

```
function grep { $input | out-string -stream | select-string $args }
function Install-SSH { Get-WindowsCapability -Online | ? Name -like 'OpenSSH.Client*' |  grep('Name\s*:\s(\S+)') | % { Add-WindowsCapability -Online -Name $_.matches.groups[1].Value } }
function Uninstall-SSH { Get-WindowsCapability -Online | ? Name -like 'OpenSSH.Client*' |  grep('Name\s*:\s(\S+)') | % { Remove-WindowsCapability -Online -Name $_.matches.groups[1].Value } }

if((([System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).groups -match "S-1-5-32-544")) {
    #Administrator Payload goes here.
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "Installing SSH..."
    Get-WindowsCapability -Online
    Pause #Debugging purposes
} else {
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red "Powershell script running as Guest. Trying to run as administrator..."
    Set-Location -Path $PSScriptRoot
    $registryPath = "HKCU:\Environment"
    $Name = "windir"
    $Value = "powershell -ep bypass -w n $PSCommandPath;#"
    Set-ItemProperty -Path $registryPath -Name $name -Value $Value
    schtasks /run /tn \Microsoft\Windows\DiskCleanup\SilentCleanup /I | Out-Null
    Remove-ItemProperty -Path $registryPath -Name $name
}
```

And I am getting the following error in the output, and I can find nothing online that helps with understanding what is going on here. What am I doing wrong?

```
Installing SSH...
Get-WindowsCapability : Set current directory to C:\WINDOWS\system32 failed:The given path's format is not supported.
At D:\Code\projects\powershell-scripts\SSHInstallation.ps1:10 char:5
+     Get-WindowsCapability -Online
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Microsoft.Dism.Commands.BaseDismObject:BaseDismObject) [Get-WindowsCapabi
   lity], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : BaseCmdLet,Microsoft.Dism.Commands.GetWindowsCapabilityCommand
```

Comment: Are you running this as a local administrator?

Comment: @Jawad I am using the same script to open itself through schtasks as an admin elevated from the current user running the script. So basically the user will run the script, and the script will elevate itself to running with admin privileges on the user who ran the file. 

e.g. If John is an admin, but uses UAC to elevate programs to Administrator permission levels, he would not have to do that to elevate the permission level of this script. The script will skip UAC and automagically run itself as John the Administrator instead of John the user.

Comment: @Jawad So yes, the script running  at line 10 char 5 is running as a local administrator. The user in my case is also a domain user who can log on using domain credentials. I have local admin PC access to all computers on my domain.